# How would a body be stored in a dark hole in the moon?

Tags: the-moon, colonization, atmosphere, cryogenics

How well would the human body stay preserved if it was frozen while pressurized and vacuum sealed before being placed in a crater on the Moon? Would the temperature be more reliably stable on the moon then can be achieved on Earth?

People sometimes choose to be frozen after death, would the moon be a more hospitable climate for frozen bodies?

Comment: The rover could not bury it, it has no mechanical parts for that. It can not move a body, it can not dig. It can only make soil samples. A body would preserve like the bodies on the Mount Everest.

Comment: There is no "dark side of the moon"; the moon rotates and all sides of it alternate two weeks of daylight with two weeks of night.

Comment: More stable than what?

Comment: @is this better?

Comment: Obligatory James P. Hogan (before he went kookoo) dead body on the moon reference: https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1339677216i/776489._UY475_SS475_.jpg

Comment: There is something fundamental missing from this question. Why would you store a dead body on the moon? Or if I read the body (and not the title) of the question correctly, what is your goal when preserving the body? Later retrieval for scientific analysis? Forensic analysis? having something identifiable to hand back to the corpse's family?

Comment: This question still needs improvement, but there is maybe some potential to it.  Muze's edit was good, but it's still not quite there yet.  If you can't address Ingolfis' concerns in a day or two, then it should be closed.

Comment: @DrSheldon is this better?

Comment: Perhaps it will help someone answer the question.  Otherwise, it might be time to let this question go, and find something else to ask.

Comment: As @RussellBorogove states there is no dark side of the moon. A body placed on the lunar surface, unless it is in a permanent shadow region of some craters would undergo cyclic cooling & warming, which is not conducive to body/biological preservation.

Comment: why not use the water and nutrients in the body,this is what we will have to do when we start living away from earth and it is how we live now our planet do this for us right now.